# How do i create an RDFa definition for something like "textNode HTMLElement textNode"?

Tags: rdfa, symfony-cmf, hallo-js

Im trying to create some custom blocks for a CMS interface based on the [symfony-cmf](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/index.html). In order for these blocks to be edited inline with createphp/hallo i need to create RDFa mappings for them.

The basic example for an included block is something like the following:

```
<type
        xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#"
        xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
        xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#"
        typeof="sioc:Post"
        >
    <attribute key="class" value="articleContainer span3"/>
    <children>
        <property property="dcterms:title" identifier="title" tag-name="h2"/>
        <property property="sioc:content" identifier="content" />
    </children>
</type>
```

Which would yield something like this:

```
<h2>The title input</h2>
<p>the content, however i beleive the actual &lt;p&gt; tag is applied by the editor</p>
```

Thats all well and good... What Im having a hard time figuring out how to define this mapping for a resource that will be something like this:

`<h1>Text string with <strong>emphasized phrase</strong> in the middle</h1>`

I could probably just use the `sioc:content` type and then rely on the user to "bold" the emphasized phrase in the editor but i would rather have it be edited explicitly.

Is there a way to do this? Also if anyone could point me towards solid RDFa tutorials that would be great. My google-fu is usually strong but all i can seem to find are the actual spec, and a bunch of posts about seemingly unrelated usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the RDFa mapping is to specify which properties of the document you want to render with which tags. Actual content typically is WYSIWYG. I guess RDFa being quite complex it would support inline-nested information like what you are asking for. But the midgard/createphp component which reads this XML configuration to generate the right data does not support nested content. I am not sure if create.js would support it, but i think not.

Note that you can map children and output whole content hierarchies. But that would not handle your emphasised fragment.